# Centering an image/logo in Bootstraps navbar?

Tags: image, twitter, twitter-bootstrap, centering, navbar

So I currently have the logo sitting in the very left of the navbar, however I would like it in the middle. I have tried almost everything on these forums and on google searches and I can't seem to change it.

Here's the code for it:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <a class="brand" href="#">
      <img alt="logo.png"src="img/logo.png" style="height:60px;>          

</div>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample which puts the logo in the middle of the toolbar: http://jsbin.com/efagoj/1/edit.

The only key changes you need to make is to give `float: none; margin: 0 auto;` to the `a` tag with `.brand` class. We add `float: none;` because in bootstrap `.brand` has a `float: left;` in it and we don't want it to be like that. `margin: 0 auto;` is to center the link.

We also need to add `text-align: center;` to the div with `container-fluid`.